# Who are Daffy duck's nephews parents?

Tags: plot-explanation, looney-tunes, a-haunting-we-will-go

In **[A haunting we will go](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060053/)**, as seen Daffy duck has nephews and three of them. What I am confused about is we never actually *see* the nephews parents, nor who they even are.

**Who are the parents of Daffy Duck's nephews**?

Comment: There were nephews or just one nephew?

Comment: ok, that one is solved :)

Comment: Any relation to Donald?  lol

Comment: In the tiny toons 'verse, Plucky is Daffy's nephew, and Mr./Mrs Duck are his parents. I think they only get shown from the neck up in one or two episodes.